# Flash swf is not playing in IE8

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

i ran into some IE8 issue and I am not yet familiar with the problem.
The video does not play using I8 and versions below. My target is only IE8. But I don't know how to implement it and am not also familiar in adobe flash.

**Question: Can I solve this issue using action scripts? If so, how can I apply the scripts exactly into my codes**

The site I'm working with is : `http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/about-us/our-culture/`

My code is shown below:

```
<body>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="172" height="250"     id="FlashID" title="printableIntro">
     <param name="movie" value="printableIntro.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
     <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" /><!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. -->
     <param name="autoplay" value="false"/>
     <param name="play" value="false"/>
     <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false" />
     <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" /><!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
   <!--[if !IE]-->
   </object>

   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="printableIntro.swf" width="172" height="250">
   <!--<![endif]-->
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
     <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
     <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
     <param name="autoplay" value="false"/>
     <param name="play" value="false"/>
     <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false" />
     <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->        
     <div>
       <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
       <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
     </div>
     <!--[if !IE]-->
   </object>
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
      swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
   </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SWFObject

https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Here is how you use it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script> 
<div id="flashcontent"> This text is replaced by the Flash movie. </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "mymovie", "400", "200", "8", "#336699"); 
  so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Here is what each parameter means

```
var so = new SWFObject(swf, id, width, height, version, background-color [, quality, xiRedirectUrl, redirectUrl, detectKey]);
```

Create a new SWFObject and pass in the required arguments:

- swf – The file path and name to your swf file.
- id – The ID of your object or embed tag. The embed tag will also have this value set as it’s name attribute for files that take advantage of swliveconnect.
- width – The width of your Flash movie.
- height – The height of your Flash movie.
- version – The required player version for your Flash content. This can be a string in the format of ‘majorVersion.minorVersion.revision’. An example would be: "6.0.65". Or you can just require the major version, such as "6".
- background-color – This is the hex value of the background color of your Flash movie.

Optional arguments are:

- quality – The quality you wish your Flash movie to play at. If no quality is specified, the default is "high".
- xiRedirectUrl – If you would like to redirect users who complete the ExpressInstall upgrade, you can specify an alternate URL here
- redirectUrl – If you wish to redirect users who don’t have the correct plug-in version, use this parameter and they will be redirected.
- detectKey – This is the url variable name the SWFObject script will look for when bypassing the detection. Default is ‘detectflash’. Example: To bypass the Flash detection and simply write the Flash movie to the page, you could add ?detectflash=false to the url of the document containing the Flash movie.

  so.write("flashcontent");

Tell the SWFObject script to write the Flash content to the page (if the correct version of the plug-in is installed on the user’s system) by replacing the content inside the specified HTML element.

Comment: Thanks SSpoke. It worked like a charm. 

I uploaded the swfobject.js to the directory where my swfobject lies. And added the javascript that you suggest with some edits with the default parameters. And it works

<code><!--[if IE 8 ]-->       
  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script> 
  <div id="flashcontent"> This text is replaced by the Flash movie. </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var so = new SWFObject("printableIntro.swf", "FlashID", "172", "250", "8", "#336699"); 
    so.write("flashcontent");
  </script>
 <!--![endif]-->
</code>